# 3-point recurrence relation for Hermite Polynomials

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

I am trying to show, given $H_{n+1} = xH_n-nH_{n-1}$,

that $<H_n,H_n>$ = $n<H_{n-1},H_{n-1}>$.

I have the solution available to me, from which I do not understand the following:

$<H_n,H_n>$ = $<H_n,xH_{n-1}-(n-1)H_{n-2}>$ = $...$

Specifically,I am confused on how does  $H_n= H_{n-1}-(n-1)H_{n-2}$?

Thanks!

Comment: Presumably your given three term recurrence relation is wrong or else your solution is wrong.

Comment: @ian This is how the question is written and the solution also follows from.  Where do you think it is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Your first relation is wrong: the (probabilists') Hermite polynomials satisfy $H_{n+1}=xH_n-H_n'$ (note the derivative!), and $H_n'=nH_{n-1}$. Hence your solution.

Comment: @ian Thanks for pointing that out! But my lecture notes, electronically typed from the lecturer and the problem-sheet itself do not mention a derivative at all. Quite confusing!

Comment: I agree with @Ian. Without refering to a derivative (it looks to trouble you), your recurrence relation should be $H_{n + 1} = xH_n - nH_{n-1}$

Comment: @JeanMarie Damn! Yes, that was a typo on my behalf - sorry for that. I'll edit my post. But, i still don't see how to show the statement I mentioned above. Thanks again!

Comment: $H_n=x H_{n-1}-(n-1)H_{n-2}$ (mind the $x$) is just the recurrence relationship written at order $n-1$.